# Stop objects from going off the screen

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I wrote this code to stop the `UIImage` going off the screen, but this only works for the left side. How could I get this code to work on the right side as well?

Note that the `UIImage` is controlled by the accelerometer:

```
CGFloat leftOfWorld = 0.0f;
CGFloat minCenterX = leftOfWorld + (person.bounds.size.width / 2.0f);
person.center = CGPointMake(MAX(minCenterX, person.center.x), person.center.y);
```

Comment: `MIN(maxCenterX, MAX(minCenterX, person.center.x))`

Comment: This didnt work, and by the way im in landscape, it stops on the left hand side of the screen but not on the right

Comment: How do you compute maxCenterX in this case?

Comment: yeah, thats what i dont know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

```
CGFloat maxCenterX = self.view.frame.size.width - (person.bounds.size.width / 2.0f);
person.center = CGPointMake(MIN(maxCenterX, person.center.x), person.center.y);
```

Comment: It didnt work, it has a border in the middle of the screen, i just need it on the edge of the screen

Comment: I don't get it, could you please explain it more precisely how do you want to limit the person position?

Comment: I want it to stop at the edge of the iphone/ipod screen i have got it to stop on the left side, but not on the right side.